# If you roll two dice in how many ways can you get 1 on atleast one die

Tags: combinatorics

If you roll two dice in how many ways can you get 1 on atleast one die?

my answer is 11 is this right?

Comment: Yes.-----------

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's right. Here's an easy way to think about it:

There are $36$ total outcomes from a roll of the dice. Of those, $5\times5=25$ don't contain a $1$.  Thus, there are $36-25=11$ rolls with at least one $1$.

Answer (score 0):

The other way to think about it would be this:

There is a pair of 1s as one possibility.

Otherwise, there will be one one and the other will be something else.  There are 5 possibilities and 2 dice to cover this so there are 10 possibilities here.

Putting these together produces 11 for a constructive way to show the 11 outcomes.